# How to add attribute to session in spring app

Tags: spring, session

I have an app for an online store. I want each user to create their own basket in which they can put some products. After that, he can edit this basket, etc. What is the best way to do this? I already asked this question here, but there was no adequate answer. I searched for information on this issue, but also could not find it in the form I needed.

I am currently using the following scheme
As soon as a user visits my site, I create a cart for him and add to the session like this:

```
@GetMapping("/")
    public String sayHello(HttpSession session) {
        session.setAttribute("bucket", new ArrayList<ProductDto>());
        return "index";
    }
```

To add something to this cart I use this method:

```
@GetMapping("/add/{id}")
    public String addProductToBucket(@SessionAttribute("bucket")ArrayList<ProductDto> bucket,
                                     @PathVariable("id") long id,
                                     Model model){
        bucket.add(productService.getById(id));
        return "redirect:/product";
    }
```

To empty the cart I just write

```
bucket.clear ();
```

Am I doing everything right or do I need to work differently? And another question. How can I set the lifetime for this object in the session? I would like him to live there conditionally 20 minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below annotated code would set "value" to "item":

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String testMestod(HttpServletRequest request){

   request.getSession().setAttribute("item",value);
   return "index.html";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the object during the user session, There are some ways:

```
//directly add one attribute to the session

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String testMestod(HttpServletRequest request){
   ShoppingCart cart = (ShoppingCart)request.getSession().setAttribute("cart",value);
   return "testJsp";
}

 //get it from the controller

ShoppingCart cart = (ShoppingCart)session.getAttribute("cart");
Make your controller session scoped


//Scope the Objects, for example, you have a user object that should be in session every time

@Component
@Scope("session")
public class User
 {
    String user;
    /*  setter getter*/
  }

//inject class in each controller that you want.

   @Autowired
   private User user

//The AOP proxy injection : in spring -xml

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd">

  <bean id="user"    class="com.User" scope="session">     
      <aop:scoped-proxy/>
  </bean>
</beans>


//Pass HttpSession to method

 String index(HttpSession session) {
            session.setAttribute("mySessionAttribute", "someValue");
            return "index";
        }

//Make ModelAttribute in session By @SessionAttributes("ShoppingCart"):

  public String index (@ModelAttribute("ShoppingCart") ShoppingCart shoppingCart, SessionStatus sessionStatus) {
//Spring V4
//you can modify session status  by sessionStatus.setComplete();
}
//or you can add Model To entire Controller Class like,

@Controller
    @SessionAttributes("ShoppingCart")
    @RequestMapping("/req")
    public class MYController {

        @ModelAttribute("ShoppingCart")
        public Visitor getShopCart (....) {
            return new ShoppingCart(....); //get From DB Or Session
        }  
      }
```

Comment: And if I want the session to be created for any user. Whether it was authenticated or not

Answer (score 0):

First you make your controller session scoped by adding  @Scope("session").

```
@Controller
@Scope("session")
```

then add one attribute to session

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String sayHello(HttpServletRequest request){
  request.getSession().setAttribute("cart",valueOfCart);
    return "index";
}
```

For session time out, in your application.properties set property server.session.timeout= value is in seconds.

then Scope the user object that should be in session every time

```
@Component
@Scope("session")
public class User
 {
    String user;
    /*getter setter*/
  }
```

then inject class in each controller that you want

```
@Autowired
   private User user
```